# Fetch Data from DynamoDB table and display it in React Application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, amazon-dynamodb, react-table

I am trying to create something like a leave planner.

This list is initially populated for 31 days like:

```
var alias_list = [., . , ......]
 var days = ['1','2','3',...'31']
export default class CalenderView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  }

  componentDidMount() {
  var DynamoDB_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://m....***z5l.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Test/'

  fetch(DynamoDB_API_ENDPOINT)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      result => {

        type_of_leave = result.body.type
        alias_on_leave = result.body.alias
        stats_of_leave = result.body.status
        date_of_leave = result.body.date

      } 
    )
    // Set state



}
render() {
    return (
      <>
      <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">

  <thead>

  <tbody>
  {
    alias_list.map((alias, sl_no) => {

        return(
          <tr>
          <td>{sl_no+1}</td>
          <td>{alias}@</td>
          {

            days.map((date,index)=>{

                return(
                      <td>  <Status alias={alias} date={date} value={'P'} variant={'success'}/> </td>
                )
            })
          }
          </tr>
        )
  })
  }


  </tbody>
  </Table>
    </>
  );
}
```

The problem is:
I want to store when the value of Status Dropdown is changed and then on refreshing the page again, this value should stay.

**Status**

```
  render() {

    if(this.props.date!=null){
      return (
        <>
        <Dropdown  size="sm">
        <Dropdown.Toggle size="sm" date={this.state.date} variant={this.state.variant} id="dropdown-basic">
        {this.state.value}
        </Dropdown.Toggle>

        <Dropdown.Menu size="sm">

          <Dropdown.Item eventKey='P' onSelect={()=>this.setP()}>P</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item eventKey='PL' onSelect={()=>this.setPL()}>PL</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item eventKey='WO' onSelect={()=>this.setWO()}>WO</Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>

      </>
    );


    }
```

I want to store the Data in DynamoDB if the status is PL or WO and delete from DynamoDB if the status is 'P'.

Populate all with P dropdown and only change the ones that are in the dynamodb table.

Anything would help. I saw things like react-table, react-grid but I am not planning to use those.

Answer (score 0):

Question is too broad ... too many problems you're trying to resolve.

Explore any todo example/tutorial to learn about react data driven 'flow'.

1. Fetch data and render view using simple components - match/convert result (DB structure, f.e. list of leaves) with component requirements (array of days)
2. Each `<Status/>` change handler should update DB but also update parent's state (to force rerendering - update view, pass new props to children) ... handler must exists in parent and be passed as prop
3. Each `<Status/>` should get more props, f.e. `date` (or day for calendar view), `id` (db record), `state` (value) and use them to render view, pass to handler ... or array of (id, person_id/name, state) to render many [changeable] records in the same day cell

### Update

> I need to store the state of each cell basically.

No, like in DB you need only not default values.

> So an object like {alias1: 1 { value: 'P', variant: 'success'}, 2:{}, 3{}.......}, alias2{1:{}.....} might help. But that would be no_of_alias * 31 * 3 values to store in the state itself and it makes the page really slow. I need a good way to store and display the state of each cell(alias, date).

Array of 31 elements are good enough. Each of them can be empty (undefined), single object or array. Mock state with something like:

```
let arr = []
arr.length = 31
arr[5] = { db_key: 'some key', alias: 'one', value: 'PL' }
arr[15] = [
  { db_key: 'some key#2', alias: 'one', value: 'PL' },
  { db_key: 'some key#3', alias: 'two', value: 'WO' }
]
```

Simply render [using `.map`] `<Status day={i+1} content={arr[i]} key={i} changeHandler= />`  (`variant` can be derived from value - I guess), date

`<Status/>` component should render only day number when data is `undefined`, one alias and dropdown for single object (check if not array) and more [sub-]rows when array [in props] exists.

Even thousends of elements in array/state should not affect rendering speed. Nodes are updated in virtual DOM and only changed components (with changed props) are rerendered.

After this try to implement fetching and converting data to desired state structure. Remember to create new objects as array (`arr[i]`) elements (not mutate existing) during updates [in handler] - required to force cell rerenderings.

Comment: Thanks @xadm I am new to react and I have been through the tutorials but couldn't get it working still. I am thinking of switching to react-table. Any suggestions?
I need to store the state of each cell basically. So an object like {alias1: 1 { value: 'P', variant: 'success'}, 2:{}, 3{}.......}, alias2{1:{}.....}
might help. But that would be no_of_alias * 31 * 3 values to store in the state itself and it makes the page really slow. I need a good way to store and display the state of each cell(alias, date).